# Should I dispose ValueNotifier object my self? Is it safe to leve it as it is?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I have a custom Stateless widget that has a `ValueNotifier` paramter as constructor paramter.

See the snippet below.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatChoiceChipList(
      choiceList: ["first item","second item","third item"],
      selectedIndex: ValueNotifier<int>(0),
      onSelected: (index) {},
    );
  }
}
```

​

Well, as you can see in the above snippet, in the build method I created a ValueNotifier object and does not dispose it later.

1. Is it safe to create the ValueNotifier within the build method?
2. should I create the ValueNotifier in the parent Stateful Widget and dispose it myself when the parent Stateful widget got disposed??

Answer (score 0):

1.You can if you want, but why don't you just declare it inside the your FlatChoiceChipList widget?

2.I believe only if you add listeners to it. This is the dispose method:

```
@mustCallSuper
void dispose() {
  assert(_debugAssertNotDisposed());
  _listeners = null;
}
```

But it's good practice to dispose when you don't need it anymore.